# Workbook_BeforePrint event not working

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I want to dynamically set some data to the header (and/or footer) of a sheet.

From several forums I found numerous examples showing how to do that, and they all seem pretty easy to understand without any difficulty.
So I applied what I read to a simple try like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = Range("A1")
End Sub
```

But it merely don't work: nothing appears in my sheet preview.

BTW the only ambiguous point in documentations was about the expression of the data to use, so I also tried replacing `Range("A1")` by `Range("A1").Text`, then by `Range("A1").Value`, also without success.

I suppose I'm missing some simple point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers already suggested, the code was fine and the problem wasn't there: in fact, the issue came from the fact that it was not invoked.

And this in turn came from a silly situation: **the Design Mode was enabled!**

With Design Mode disabled, all works fine...

Answer (score 2):

Your code worked for me. Also tested your code with some extra lines for debugging:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print "Running Workbook_BeforePrint"
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = Range("A1")
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Before printing, the footer was empty; after printing, the footer in Preview matched A1 and "Running Workbook_BeforePrint" was in the Immediate window.

Comment: I discovered what was wrong (look at my own answer), thanks to your answer. First I added  a `Debug.Print` like you suggested, and observed that nothing appeared in the execution window. It enforced the idea that the event was not fired, so I wanted to add a `Debug.Print` in a working macro... and it's how I discovered I'd left Design Mode enabled! I can't really "accept" your answer but it's certainly the way I understood what happened, so I upvote it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `beforeprint` that isn't working, it's the `.centerfooter`. Try instead:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = CStr(Cells(1, 1))
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835588.aspx) explicitly calls for a `string`, but I'm not sure why it explicitly needs it as a `string` even if it already is a string in the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it keeps not displaying anything! BTW I also had a try directly with `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Some text"` and it was yet the same. Might not it be that the `Private Sub` is merely never called? But I can't figure out  why...

Comment: It works for me just like that, on 2007. Do you have it in `ThisWorkbook` module?

Comment: Reading your last comment I thought "Alleluia", because I had it in the involved sheet module instead. But... after moving it into the `ThisWorkBook` module, it keeps not working! Any other idea? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Check yourApplication.EnableEvents is true before print sheet